# How old is Wanda Maximoff in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, age, scarlet-witch

Despite being played by a then 27 year-old actress, dialogue in *Captain America: Civil War* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* implies that Wanda Maximoff is younger than she seems and [Dawson Casting](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DawsonCasting) is in play.

> Clint: Ultron has these allies, these uh, kids, they're punks really. They carry a big damn stick and Nat took a serious hit. Someone's gonna have to teach 'em some manners.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

> Steve: She's a kid!
>
> ...
>
> Clint: ...you can go to high school.
>
> <sub>*Captain America: Civil War*</sub>

Do we know her exact age?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211905/whose-birthyears-are-canonically-established-in-the-mcu

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My old answer is below as most of it is still correct, the only problematic part is using Clint's "high school" comment to narrow down the age range further which we now see was way out.

In *WandaVision* we finally get a year for when the twins were born, Woo gives a very brief rundown on Wanda and he says she was born in 1989.

> **Jimmy Woo:** Quick history on our subject. Born in Sokovia in 1989 to Irina and Oleg Maximoff, both killed during an air raid when Maximoff and her twin brother, Pietro, were ten.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 5, "On a Very Special Episode..."</sub>

However, and interestingly in the same scene we get a view of the screen that shows information about Wanda and some clips of her. On this screen it also states her year of birth to be 1988 not 1989. Whilst Jimmy could be incorrect I imagine this is just a mistake from the art department and any dialogue should really take precedence as it would be noticed a lot more easily to correct.

[image: Wanda's file shown on the screen with various information about her including a birthyear of 1988]

This also ties in well with the death of her parents and the attack on Sokovia. A newspaper shown in that same scene on the screen dates the attack 1999/03/31 and as seen in the original answer the twins were ten at the time of the attack.

[image: The Daily newspaper with the headline "Sokovia Under Attack" dated "March 31, 1999"]

Considering all this they were likely born early on in 1989 as to be 10 at the time of the attack. That means at the time of *Avengers: Infinity War* in 2018 Wanda would be 29.

---

As far as I can tell there is no official information on Wanda's birth date but we can narrow down the range for why they could have been born.

#### She was ten when the bomb hit and blames Tony Stark

> **Pietro Maximoff:** We were ten years old, having dinner, the four of us. When the first shell hits, two floors below, it makes a hole in the floor. It's big. Our parents go in, and the whole building starts coming apart. I grab her, roll under the bed and the second shell hits. But, it doesn't go off. It just...sits there in the rubble, three feet from our faces. And on the side of the shell is painted one word...
>
> **Wanda Maximoff:** Stark.
>
> **Pietro Maximoff:** We were trapped two days.
>
> **Wanda Maximoff:** Every effort to save us, every shift in the bricks, I think, "This will set it off." We wait for two days for Tony Stark to kill us.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

#### Tony was CEO from 1992 to 2010

According to the SHIELD case files supplied with *The Avengers* DVD release Tony was born in 1970.

[image: Tony's SHIELD case file]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Tony is made CEO at 21 after his parents died and as they died in [December 1991](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95754/58193) this presumably happened in 1992 before his birthday.

> **Voice over:** Then, the passing of a titan. Howard Stark's lifelong friend and ally, Obadiah Stane, steps in to help fill the gap left by the legendary founder, until, at age 21, the prodigal son returns and is anointed the new CEO of Stark Industries.
>
> <sub>*Iron Man*</sub>

In 2010 Tony then hands over the CEO position to Pepper Potts.

> **Tony Stark:** I hereby irrevocably appoint you chairman and CEO of Stark Industries effective immediately. Yeah, done deal. Okay?
>
> <sub>*Iron Man 2*</sub>

All this together means that the twins would have been born from 1981 up to 2000 making them 15 to 34 in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*. Of course the twins could blame Stark still after he left the company but considering the move away from being a weapons manufacturer it seems unlikely this would have happened then.

Clearly they don't appear to be at either end of the scale in the films so we could narrow it down further assuming Clint is correct in saying that Wanda could go to High School.

> **Clint Barton:** You gotta help me, Wanda. Look, you wanna mope, can go to high school.
>
> <sub>*Captain America: Civil War*</sub>

High School age is from 13 to 18 and *Civil War* takes place in 2016 so from there we can calculate that should would have been born between 1998 to 2003. As we already have a range capping out in 2000 that means they would have been born from 1998 to 2000.

If she was born in 1998 that would make her 10 during the events of *Iron Man* which would tie up quite nicely with Stark's move away from being a weapon's manufacturer and keep it tied into the MCU so it seems possible this is when she was born.

Therefore, as of *Avengers: Infinity War* (just to make it easier due to the Blip), she would either be 18 or 20, presumably closer to the latter to make her age in the earlier films a bit higher.

Comment: The new info puts her born around at the same was actually born IRL (Feb. 16, 1989).

Comment: Clint wasn't saying she was young enough that she really *could* go to high school, he was clearly stating that if she wanted to act like a mopey teenager then she *should* go to where mopey teenagers are, ie high school. Also, it wouldn't be unusual for someone like him to dismiss her as a kid, even if she wasn't that much younger. I do the same thing to younger firefighters in my department even if they are in their 20s and 30s.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Yeah re-reading that part I put too much weight on Clint's statement there being reflective of her actual age and you're right. And as someone who is ~20 years younger than anyone else in my company I'm well aware of the condescending dismissal people can get just because of their age.