# Whose birthyears are canonically established in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Tony Stark and Cap travel to 1970 and Tony speaks with his father Howard, who is expecting his first child (Tony).

So this establishes that Tony Stark was born in 1970 or 1971.

**What other major characters in the MCU have their ages/birthyears established canonically?**

For the purpose of this question "established" means that either their year of birth is stated, or we know their exact age (in years) in a specific year.   (One year of error because of uncertainty about when in the year their birthday occurs is okay.)   Approximate ages do not suffice.   Movie/TV canon only.

Comment: Obvious answers:  Cassie Lang, Vision, and I think Steve Rogers and Bucky while registering for the army??

Comment: And note, "Thor is 1500" is not specific enough.

Comment: Thor’s a god. When it comes to his age, you’ll take what you’re given, and like it.

Comment: Based on Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2, Peter Quill was conceived in 1980 and presumably born in 1981.

Comment: It gets kind of tricky figuring out the ages of the Asgardians, but Odin's battle against the Frost Giants at the beginning of the first Thor movie is established as taking place in 965 A.D.  Later in that campaign, Odin loses his eye and finds Loki as a baby on Jotunheim.  If Loki and Thor are the same age (in Ragnarok, Thor recounts a childhood story and says "We were eight at the time"), and if neither the battle nor their infancy lasted decades, then they were both born close to 965 A.D.  Which doesn't square with Thor being 1500, but there you are.

Comment: @NathanK.   Nice sleuthing.   If this weren't contradicted by other dialog (1500, right) then it would suffice.   But I guess we must assume the there are different years in play.   And we don't know how Loki ages.   So I don't think we're firm enough.

Comment: Stark was probably born in 1970, it seemed like late summer at the latest and Howard describes her as quite far along.

Comment: Then again, Howard seemed like he had no clue what was going on, so maybe there were another 6 months left -- who knows.

Comment: Does Baby Groot count as having his own birthday separate from OG Groot?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I mean, if Thor gave me _anything_ I'd like it too! ;-)

Answer (score 27):

#### Cap

Steve Rogers is confirmed as being born in 1918 during the events of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.

When they enter the room where Arnim Zola's computerised brain is stored, Zola says something like:

> Zola: Rogers, Steven: Born 1918.

#### Widow

Black Widow's year of birth (1984) is mentioned in the same scene as Cap's.

> Zola: Romanov, Natalia Alianovna: Born 1984

(The quote might be a little off as I'm going from memory and a quick search couldn't get me the exact lines.)

#### Bucky

<s>In *Infinity War*, which is set in 2018, Bucky refers to himself as a "semi-stable hundred year old man" when Cap and the others arrive, indicating (not definitively) that he was also born in 1918 like Cap.</s>

The memorial at the Howling Commandos museum exhibit lists Bucky as born in 1916 or 1917, depending on whether you look at the text or the bottom line (as noted by Aliden in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211905/whose-birthyears-are-canonically-established-in-the-mcu/211907#comment577894_211907)).

[image: Bucky's memorial]

#### Spidey

During the events of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, Tony Stark refers to Peter Parker as being fourteen, to which Peter corrects that he's fifteen.  If we know exactly which year this film occurred in (I'm not too sure given the “Eight years later” vs “Six years ago” issue) then we also know what age Spider-Man is.

A shot of the trailer for *Spider-Man: Far From Home* lists his birth date as being the 10th of August.

[image: Spidey's ID]

#### Fury

Nick Fury's date of birth is given on his ID card, shown in *Captain Marvel* (pinched from [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207485/how-old-is-nick-fury/207486#207486)) showing he was born on 4th July 1950.

[image: Nick Furys' ID]

#### Wanda (and Pietro) Maximoff

A full answer is given [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215669/3823)

**Summary**

- 1916/1917 Bucky Barnes
- 1918 Steve Rogers
- 1950 Nick Fury
- 1970/1971 Tony Stark
- 1980/1981 Peter Quill
- 1984 Natalia Romanov
- 1989 Wanda (and Pietro) Maximoff

Comment: In *Winter Soldier*, I believe the Smithsonian Institution voiceover about Bucky says that he and Cap were "inseparable on the school yard" which implies that they were in the same elementary school grade.  That would put his date of birth in the 1917 to 1919 range.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an Easter Egg that Fury is born on the 4th of July?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Possibly - the Marvel Movies Fandom wikia entry for Steve Rogers actually says he was also born on 4th July - I haven't mentioned that specifically as I'm not 100% sure where they got that from

Comment: @Dave:   I hope you're okay with my addition to the end.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I'd be happier if there was something (a quote or image or even a scene reference) mentioned from the film that indicated Quill's age - fine with the summary block though :)

Comment: @Dave:   Well, I assume this is based on the flashback scenes being titlecarded in 1980.   And I think we can assume Quill's father wasn't on Earth for years or that the pregnancy lasted years.   I guess you're right it's not quite as firm as the others.

Comment: @Dave:  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8jM16k61fg).   It's clear to me he is conceived in 1980, presumably the summer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Fair enough, I couldn't remember if the title cards showed the years or just the locations...

Comment: Vision is created during the events of Age of Ultron, which is 2015, FWIW

Comment: Bucky is definitively 1917, as we see his birth and death year listed on his memorial poster in the Captain America/Howling Commandos exhibit.

Comment: Amusingly, in the picture that establishes Bucky's birth year as 1917, it says he was born in 1916 at the beginning of the paragraph text

Comment: You can probably nail down Peter Parker's age based on the fact that in Homecoming, he's a high school - what, junior, senior?  I'm pretty sure they say it at some point.  That would also presumably get the approximate age of all his classmates, though Spidey is likely the only one we'll have to the day.

Comment: As noted in the comments on the OP, per Endgame, Cap and Stark go back to 1970, where Tony meets his dad Howard, who is expecting.  So Tony should be born late 1970 or early 1971.

Comment: To everyone bringing up Peter Parker, the problem is that it is inconclusive in what year Homecoming takes place.

Comment: "Zola: Romanov, Nataliya Alianova: Born 1984" — bloody millennials, always carrying out covert spy missions for opposing factions and destabilising delicate geopolitical situations.

Comment: See this answer regarding Wanda Maximoff

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Parker is pretty much a genius though, so he could be younger

Answer (score 2):

To determine the canonical birth years of some of these characters, I used the book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)* as a reference. This book provides a chronological overview of the events and characters in the MCU.

#### Kamala Khan / Ms. Marvel: 2008 or 2009

One of the youngest heroes in the MCU is Kamala Khan, also known as Ms. Marvel. She makes her debut in the TV series *Ms. Marvel*, which takes place in Fall 2025, according to the official timeline. In the first episode, she reveals that she is 16 years old, so we can infer that she was born either in 2008 or 2009. She also appeared in the movie *The Marvels*, which is set right after the post-credits scene of the final episode of *Ms. Marvel* Season 1, as [confirmed by director Nia DaCosta](https://www.looper.com/1369543/how-old-kamala-khan-the-marvels-ms-marvel-mcu-age/), which means she's still 16 years old at the time of the film's events.

[image]

#### Marc Spector / Moon Knight: March 9, 1987

In *Moon Knight* (TV series), we get a glimpse of Marc Spector’s US passport, which shows his date of birth as March 9, 1987. This means that Marc was 38 years old at the time of the series, which is set in Spring 2025 as per the official timeline.

[image: Marc Spector's passport]

[image: relevant part of the official timeline described above]

#### Kate Bishop / Hawkeye: 2002

The official timeline places *Hawkeye* (TV series) in December 2024, where we learn that Kate Bishop is 22 years old. Later, in the mid-credits scene of *The Marvels*, which follows right after *Ms. Marvel* (set in Fall 2025), Kate Bishop mentions that she is 23 years old. From this information, we can deduce that her birth year is 2002.

[image: relevant part of the official timeline described above]

#### Monica Rambeau: 1983 or 1984

Monica Rambeau appears as a child in *Captain Marvel*, which takes place in the summer of 1995, according to the official timeline. The actress who portrayed her in the film, Akira Akbar, was credited as “Monica Rambeau (11 Years Old)," implying that Monica was born in either 1983 or 1984. This is further supported by the fact that Azari Akbar, who played Monica in flashbacks (set in the late 1980s), was credited as “Monica Rambeau (5 Years Old)”. This puts Monica’s birth year in either 1983 or 1984.

[image: relevant part of the official timeline described above]

#### Aaron Davis / Prowler: April 15, 1984

[image: Aaron Davis' date of birth as revealed by Karen]

Aaron Davis’ date of birth was revealed by Karen, the AI in Spider-Man’s suit, in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*. She used facial recognition to scan his face and searched law enforcement databases to find his records.

#### Peter Parker / Spider-Man: August 10, 2001

[In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, which is set in the fall of 2016 according to the official timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/280543/7957), Peter tells Tony Stark that he is 15 years old. This means he was born in either 2000 or 2001, depending on when his birthday falls. Luckily, we have a clue about that as well. In the [teaser trailer for *Spider-Man: Far From Home*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYYtuKyMtY8), we get a glimpse of Peter’s passport, which shows his date of birth as August 10. Putting these pieces together, we can conclude that Peter was born on August 10, 2001.

[image: Peter Parker's passport]
[image: Relevant part of the official timeline]

#### Peter Quill / Star-Lord: 1980

The official timeline confirms that Peter Quill was born in 1980. This is also evident from a flashback scene in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*, where we witness Meredith Quill and Ego enjoying a romantic day in 1980, suggesting that Peter was conceived shortly after.

According to the official timeline, the events of the first *Guardians of the Galaxy* film took place in the summer of 2014, followed by the second one in the fall of the same year. This puts Peter at 33 or 34 years old during the events of these two films.

[image: relevant part of the official timeline described above]

> ##### 1980 | Ego Expands to Earth
>
> After thousands of years of planting the seeds of his universal Expansion, the Celestial known as Ego sends his avatar to Earth (specifically, Missouri) and falls in love with the human Meredith Quill. She gives birth to a son, Peter, and raises him mostly as a single mother. Ego finds himself inextricably drawn back to Meredith, but he implants a tumor in her head that will eventually kill her—a murderous impulse derived from a wish to avoid entanglements that might distract from his grand plan.

James Gunn, the director of the *Guardians of the Galaxy* trilogy, also verified this in a [tweet](https://web.archive.org/web/20220430200723/https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/863882306431328257), where he answered a fan’s question about Peter’s birthday.

[image]

> **Q:** @JamesGunn When is Peter's birthday? Because if he was conceived in 1980, how was he born in 1980?

> **James Gunn:** I can’t believe how many people have asked me this. Guys, a pregnancy IS ONLY 9 MONTHS (& she could already be pregnant at the start of 2)."

#### Sam Wilson / Falcon / Captain America: September 23, 1978

A [“Marvel Studios Secret Archives” video was uploaded by the official Marvel Latin America Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=833044847286266), which revealed that Sam Wilson was born on September 23, 1978.

[image: relevant screenshot of the above video]

#### Loki: 965 — give or take a year

According to the official timeline, Loki was adopted by Odin as a baby around 965 CE. We can reasonably guess that he was born during that year — give or take a year. This means that Loki was about 1053 years old when he faced his tragic fate in *Avengers: Infinity War*, which happened in Spring 2018, according to the official timeline.

[image: part of the official timeline stating the above]

Answer (score -2):

Honestly, I don't believe Bucky knows how old he is. I mean, in *The Falcon and The Winter Soldier*, he say's that he's 106 years old. When his canon birth year is 1917, which would make him 107. Even though it could be possible that he hasn't had his birthday yet, *TFATWS* is set in mid 2024. Which would mean he is 107, so the comment about him being "a semi-stable 100 year old man" could be a nod to that.

Comment: Sounds like you're replying to the other answer here, rather than the question. Since you posted this as an answer, it should directly address the actual question.

Comment: If you're supporting that his canonical birth year is 1917 (which is noted in the other answer), you should give some better evidence for it than is in the other answer.